# Copy a folder into another folder (Windows 7) via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm able to copy the contents of folder A into folder B but folder A itself isn't being copied into folder B.

Folder `A`(StockMarket) and its subfolders

```
Directory of C:\Users\Moondra\Downloads\StockMarket

5/23/2017  07:33 PM    <DIR>          .
5/23/2017  07:33 PM    <DIR>          ..
5/23/2017  07:33 PM    <DIR>          data
              0 File(s)              0 bytes
              3 Dir(s)  54,977,626,112 bytes free
```

Folder `B` `stocks`

`C:\Users\Moondra\Downloads\Stocks`

using

`xcopy StockMarket stocks /e /i`

`robocopy StockMarket stocks /s /i`

I'm able to copy the insides of `StockMarket` into `Stocks`, but not the `StockMarket` folder itself.

Is there a way to copy the `StockMarket` folder as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xcopy`:

`xcopy StockMarket stocks\StockMarket /e /i`

This will essentially copy the contents of `StockMarket` to a new folder in `stocks`, called `StockMarket`.

Comment: This. The reason you have to have stocks\StockMarket as the destination is because the xcopy command is reading the inside of StockMarket as the copying source.